# iOS - Show UIActivityIndicatorView when table is being loaded

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a tab bar application. I have 2 questions.

- Using a default image for the
  application does that enable the
  application to initialize itself (the
  first view that is showed in
  MainView.xib) in the background while
  the image is being displayed?
- Touching the second tab in the
  application, the application will
  load data into a `UITableView`. This
  takes some time (fetching some data
  from the internet) so going from the
  first tab to the second tab there is
  a delay before the table is being
  showed in the second tab. I want to
  display a `UIActivityIndicatorView` while
  the `UITableView` is being populated
  and then want the
  `UIActivityIndicatorView` to disappear
  when the `UITableView` is finished
  loading. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I added the objective-c code.

Comment: If my answer was the correct one, please mark as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. YES. Even if you don't give any default image, it will load the first view controller showing a black screen.
2. Display the activity indicator view in your second view controller's `loadView`. And, put all the loading code in your second view controllers `viewDidAppear:` method. By doing this, your second view controller will be displayed with the activity indicator view as soon as you press the second tab. And after the loading is completed, dismiss the activity indicator. This will give you a smooth transition from one tab to the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please examplify with some code?

Answer (score 10):

You can use this inside the activity:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("The information is gathered, one moment please.");
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return progress;
}
```

This will show an alert once you call this in(or on) the activity:

```
showDialog(0x0001);
```

When the dialog has to fade out call this:

```
removeDialog(0x0001);
```

**EDIT**

Now for objective-c:

```
UIAlertView alert = [UIAlertView initWithTitle:@"a title" message:@"a message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]
[alert show];

if(alert != nil) {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

        indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width/2, alert.bounds.size.height-45);
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [alert addSubview:indicator];
        [indicator release];
}
```

**EDIT**
Removing it is done with this:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[alert release];
```

**/EDIT**

That worked for me:) it could be its not totally spot on becouse i changed some stuff in the browser to now thow company secrets etc xD :).
Feel free to ask stuff about it.

Comment: Thanks, but this question is pertaining to Objective-C in general and iOS in specific (not Android).

Comment: oh im sorry, i opened the wrong project, no even the wrong os... ill give you a working ios version in a moment.

Comment: Thanks!, so how do you know in the code when the UITableView (in my case has finished loading the data so that you can dismiss the UIActivityIndicatorView?)

Comment: I used this for the exact same thing. what i do is getting the data from internet in a seperate class, when the method that handles this is called an alert is started. Then it will download (and parse xml in my case) and put the downloaded/parsed info in the array. when that is done i stop the alert and open the new page. becouse ios will always only load what is shown on the screen it wont take a long amount of time. The rest is loaded while scrolling up/down.

Comment: Can you show me code where you stop the alert after the array has been populated?

Comment: Added it to the answer after the second EDIT